# Regular expression in Rails scope not capturing the right values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, named-scope

I would like to capture rows with "0" when I have values such as this:

"**0**,1,8,9,10" 
"10" 
"**0**,1" 
"4,5" 
"1,5,10"

The code that I inherited was capturing values both "0" and "10" which is wrong:

```
scope :short_result_contains_value, -> (game_id, value) { where(game_id: game_id).where('short_result LIKE ?', "%#{value}%")
```

I'm trying to use Regex to tighten up the search query but I couldn't get the regex to capture any values at all:

```
scope :short_result_contains_value, -> (game_id, value) { where(game_id: game_id).where('short_result ~ ?', "/\b(#{value})\b/")}
```

When I run it, I see in the log that the following query is being run:

```
SELECT "game_results".* FROM "game_results" WHERE "game_results"."game_id" = $1 AND "game_results"."game_id" = $2 AND (short_result ~ (0')
```

ActiveRecord is not capturing any of the values when it should be. How can the regex be fixed? Thanks!

I am using Postgres and am on Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.3.7.

Comment: Try `where('short_result LIKE ?', "#{value},%")` if you plan to only return rows starting with `value` and followed with a comma.

Comment: I got the following query in the log: (short_result LIKE '0, %'), it also didn't return any results..

Comment: Well, there should be no space between `,` and `%`.

Comment: Are rows always sorted like in example (so that 0 is always at beginning)?

Comment: @Vasfed No, it will be in random order

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahh gotcha! Worked now, thanks!

Comment: @MLZ it will not work for rows like `"1,2,0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
where('short_result LIKE ?', "#{value},%")
```

It will only return rows starting with `value` and followed with a comma.

The `LIKE` pattern should match the whole record. Here, `value` is `0`, so the record should start with `0`. Then, a comma should follow. Then the `%` wildcard matches any 0+ chars there are to the end of the record.

If you plan to match the value as a whole word you need

```
.where('short_result ~ ?', "\\y#{value}\\y")
```

The `\y` in PostgreSQL regex syntax is a word boundary, same as `\b` in Perl-like regexps.

If you only want to match a value in between commas or start/end of string use

```
.where('short_result ~ ?', "(^|,)#{value}($|,)")
```

The `(^|,)` matches a start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a comma, and `($|,)` matches either the end of a string (`$`) or a comma.

Comment: This will not work for values that are not in the beginning or single values without a comma

Comment: @Vasfed Sure, it should not match those NOT in the beginning, see OP.

Comment: See comments to OP - values are in random order, also even if the data is like in original example - try searching for `5` or `9`

Comment: @Vasfed I added several additional solutions.

Comment: I believe the correct one is the one with whole word matching

Comment: @Vasfed you are right, the one that worked for me was the one for the whole word matching. Thank you both for your feedback, much appreciated.